# Manage exceptions between servlet and jsp

Tags: java, jsp, exception, servlets, tiles

If I have a servlet that throws the exception, how can I handle the exception so that jsp the calling page, reload only the body?

I have a servlet that does this:

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {


            try {
               .....
            } catch (Throwable th) {

               throw new ServletException(th);
            }
        }
```

My error.jsp is made in this way:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>


    <tiles:insert page="/include/baseLayout.jsp" flush="true">
        <tiles:put name="header" value="/include/header.jsp" />
        <tiles:put name="menu" value="/include/menu.jsp" />
        <tiles:put name="body" value="/include/body.jsp" />
        <tiles:put name="footer" value="/include/footer.jsp" />
    </tiles:insert>
```

The tiles.defs.xml is done this way:

......

```
 <definition name="error" extends="baseLayout" controllerClass="it.present.mininterno.prum.localizzazione.exception.ExceptionHandler">
        <put name="body" value="/include/body.jsp" />
    </definition>
```

How do I run only recharge the part of the body of the page with
an error message? The program is made with struts and when I have an exception
the action can do this. With normal servlet no !!

Comment: The struts-config is done in this way:                                             <global-exceptions>
  <exception key="label.exception" type="java.lang.Exception"
   handler="ExceptionHandler"
   path="pages/error.jsp" />
 </global-exceptions>

Comment: isn't it better to check data before sending, or implement any other type of response, for example to make ajax call and respond to it with desired body upon failure, instead of just throwing exceptions from such thing as servlet?

Comment: It would be better. In the jsp page I call the servlet with an ajax call and I should handle the exception with ajax, right?  So, in the jsp I have this:                        $.ajax({
                    url: "getSomething", 
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    data: {},
                    success: function (data) {}});                                                                                                           Do I add section error?I'm beginner with ajax.